# Android: Shall I have access to resources from my own class?

Tags: android, resources, bitmap

I my project I have a class that in this class I want to have access to properties of a picture. But I don't want to show it through this class. In this class I just want to know width and height of image and do some mathematical functions to return something.

My problem is I can't have access to resources. for example, when I write

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.tasnim);
```

It says the method getResources() in undefined for the type Stego (stego is my class name).

Please tell me what should I do?

```
public class Stego()
{
    Public Stego(){
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.tasnim);
        imWidth  = image.getWidth();
        imHeight = image.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`getResources()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) function belongs to the [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class. So unless your `Stego` class directly (or indirectly) extends `Context`, there is no `getResources()` function available.

So what you need to do is pass along a reference to your application's context (e.g. in the constructor of your `Stego` class or similar). Or if all you need is a single resource ID it might be easier to just pass along that ID.

This could for instance look like this:

```
public class Stego()
{
    Public Stego(Context myAppContext){
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myAppContext.getResources(), R.drawable.tasnim);
        imWidth  = image.getWidth();
        imHeight = image.getHeight();
    }
}
```

From your activity you can then initialize an instance of your `Stego` class like this:

```
Stego stego = new Stego(this);
```

Comment: @Hesam: as I said in the answer, you *need to pass along a reference to your application's context*. I've added a small code sample.